# Variable Assignment in Bash

Tags: bash, unix

```
for i in {0..10}
do 
  args='{"args": [ "createProperty", "Property$i", "StreetNumer$i", "StreetName$i", "City$i", "State$i", "County$i", "ZipCode$i", "TaxID$i", "PropertyType$i", "CreationDate$i", "CreatingOrganization$i" ,"publicKey$i"]}'
  echo $args
done
```

Comment: I am not able to interpolate i variable in args. it is showing $i as it is

Comment: Parameter expansion is not performed within single quotes.

Comment: thanks. could you please let me know the correct code for getting the expected output

Comment: I suggest to replace all `"` with `\"` and all `'` with `"` and `$args` with `"$args"`.

Comment: Thanks everyone. This trick worked.